# Android understand app crash in native code. Are there memory dumps?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, native

I have a Xamarin Android application that exhibit crashes only on Samsung Devices:

- Samsung Galaxy S7 (herolte), Android 8.0
- Samsung Galaxy A5(2017) (a5y17lte), Android 8.0

Here are the backtrace found in the google play console, which is identical whatever the above devices:

backtrace:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.hygeex.yaka <<<

      #00  pc 000000000006b410  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
      #01  pc 000000000001dbd0  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+88)
      #02  pc 00000000004376dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+528)
      #03  pc 0000000000437dec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime7AborterEPKc+24)
      #04  pc 0000000000522a3c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN7android4base10LogMessageD1Ev+900)
      #05  pc 00000000002d5b80  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1716)
      #06  pc 00000000002d5e4c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+176)
      #07  pc 00000000003416a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI20CallStaticIntMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+1356)
      #08  pc 000000000000de38  /data/app/com.hygeex.yaka-T6n754d07KzW5sX3abVDWQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
      #09  pc 000000000000ddcc  /data/app/com.hygeex.yaka-T6n754d07KzW5sX3abVDWQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
      #10  pc 00000000000047ec  <anonymous>
```

I have absolutely no idea what is going on.

I know how to debug a native crash on Windows and I am wondering if I could find a memory dump of the app at the time of the crash on the affected devices?

---

EDIT: Problem solved in [AppCenter with Xamarin.Android 16.3](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/742729/xamarinandroid-app-wont-start-anymore-on-samsung-p.html?childToView=745674#comment-745674)

---

EDIT: I've been able to get a complete backtrace using adb logcat crash

```
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: mid == null
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]     in call to CallStaticIntMethodV
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]     from void mono.android.Runtime.init(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String[])
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x7308ad68 self=0x74d40c0a00
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   | sysTid=31816 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x74d92919c8
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   | state=R schedstat=( 678951892 18869996 178 ) utm=19 stm=48 core=7 HZ=100
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   | stack=0x7fcaca9000-0x7fcacab000 stackSize=8MB
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   native: #00 pc 0000000000397614  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   native: #01 pc 000000000045dde8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   native: #02 pc 00000000002d59e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1040)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   native: #03 pc 00000000002d5f50  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+176)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   native: #04 pc 00000000003417ac  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI20CallStaticIntMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+1356)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   native: #05 pc 000000000000de38  /data/app/com.hygeex.yaka-_--EXZe6WtzqqDxolwYsKg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk (???)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   native: #06 pc 000000000000ddcc  /data/app/com.hygeex.yaka-_--EXZe6WtzqqDxolwYsKg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk (???)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   native: #07 pc 00000000000047ec   (???)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at mono.android.Runtime.init(Native method)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at mono.MonoPackageManager.LoadApplication(MonoPackageManager.java:57)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   - locked <0x02737249> (a java.lang.Object)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:35)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6578)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6133)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6043)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java:-1)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
09-22 18:12:58.952 31816 31816 F zygote64: runtime.cc:516]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Try to check this in your android options : Select Android project > Properties >Android Options> Advanced.

Comment: I actually have the same crash in Release mode only.

Comment: Are you using Android App Bundles instead of APKs?

Comment: @AlexeyShikov See [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/742729/xamarinandroid-app-wont-start-anymore-on-samsung-p.html)

Comment: @OlivierMATROT that is exactly the issue we had and we fixed it by reverting back to using APK. Thanks for the link!